# Web3py send_raw_transaction ValueError: {'message': 'invalid remainder', 'code': -32000}

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, ganache

I`m trying to start working with ethereum platfrom and web3py.
I want to call smart contract, build transaction, sign and send it.

Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract UselessWorker {

    int public successfullyExecutedIterations = 0;
    bytes32 public hash = '';
    
    function doWork(int _iterations) public {
        successfullyExecutedIterations = _iterations;
        for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
        {
            hash = keccak256("ABC");
        }
    }

}
```

And my python code:

```py
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))

abi = json.loads('''...''')
contract_address = '0xF0af88Da01E12D49d12300487DDa6E9C6b809AA2'

user_address = '0x348C8455A4C87849A6cd5D1E1bF397291378b51C'
private_key = 'bbd61e7e879cfa63bbdd1202bcc8ff25e4a54a08db3848ebffcc36ffbee6cd45'

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address), abi=abi)
transaction = contract.functions.doWork(555).buildTransaction({
    'gas': 200000,
    'maxFeePerGas': web3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.toWei('50', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(user_address),
    'from': user_address,
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

Every time I trying to run this code I get exception. How can I fix this?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Python\web3\main.py", line 107, in <module>
    web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
  File "D:\Program files\Python 310\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 722, in send_raw_transaction
    return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
  File "D:\Program files\Python 310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "D:\Program files\Python 310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "D:\Program files\Python 310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'invalid remainder', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: invalid remainder\n    at Object.decode (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\rlp\\src\\index.ts:75:11)\n    at StateManager.queueRawTransaction (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\statemanager.js:298:29)\n    at GethApiDouble.eth_sendRawTransaction (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\geth_api_double.js:338:14)\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\geth_api_double.js:109:10)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:107:12)', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

set 'chainId' in your transaction.
i faced the same issue and then i set 'chainId' and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).